# Raspberry pi camera freezing

Tags: raspberry-pi, camera

I have a Raspberry Pi Compute Module 4 computed to Raspberry Pi V2.1 camera. When trying to get camera output the kernel freezes.

[my camera output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5EBeZ.png)

Also when trying to read from camera using OpenCV I get error:

```
VIDIOC_STREAMON: Invalid argument
Error: Could not open video
```

has someone this experience? What is the solution?
Thank you

Comment: I have no idea if it is relevant here but many folk have issues when they use *"sub-optimal"* power supplies. Invest in a decent one.

Comment: Do you mean camera supply? A camera is supplied from Raspberry Pi and I measured 3.29V on the side pins. It seems the camera is correctly detected...

Comment: I mean a stable supply that is always able to supply enough power to the Compute Module and camera under any load.

Comment: I am sorry, the root cause was in a boot script rc.local where I have added some tasks to run and add & to every line end including the last one to fork separate process as described here https://www.dexterindustries.com/howto/run-a-program-on-your-raspberry-pi-at-startup/ But I am not sure why it causes the vc driver (or maybe encoder) freeze?

Comment: I had a similar issue, it was the power supply, upgrading to a better one might solve the issue.